# Detect all classes used in a script, and load them

Tags: php, oop

Is there a PHP library or extension that will inspect your code, find all the classes you use, and then go and automatically load those clases?

When I write a new script, it's tedious to have to write a ton of require() statements.

I know Facebook uses something very similar to "https://github.com/facebook/libphutil", which lets you just run a line in terminal and have all your dependencies loaded, no require() lines or manually maintained autoload map anywhere in the code. (This isn't an answer since I don't believe it's a stable release)

Comment: An autoloader is "as verbose as require()"...?! Wut? You write a few lines of code for an autoloader *once*, which then works *everywhere*.

Comment: An autoloader certainly isn't verbose: a single block of code that does an include, and is called automatically whenever a class is referenced in a script.... perhaps 5 lines of code in all

Comment: Right, but you still need to manually maintain a map of all classes that you have.

Comment: That's where you use a sensible directory and naming structure, so the name of a class makes clear in which file it resides automatically.

Comment: @deceze it is still more breakable than something like libphutil.

Comment: Let's put it this way: autoloading is a feature used by ginormous projects to successfully load all their stuff in a reliable manner and has been for quite a while. *Without* needing to write any code to do so. I don't know what problem you have with it...

Comment: Because it's easier for me to run a 1 line command in Unix than maintaining an autoload map. Yes, it is easy to maintain an autoload map, but it's easier to have it generated.

Comment: i will tell it in non programming language.... _stop being lazy_. if you want to write a prgram, then more chance is that you have to type some keys on that keyboard.

Comment: Again: **you do not need to maintain a map if you maintain a sensible program layout.** If your file structure is crap you're going to have headaches one way or the other.

Comment: @deceze subdirectories move around all the time, are you going to update the autoload map everytime that happens?

Comment: @DonnyP think of the number of times you will have to run that build step, the amount of work to copy/maintain that supporting structure when you create or move projects, and the things that it will prevent you from doing without extra work (use test frameworks that include your files directly, now they must include your build output files, meaning you have two copies, etc.). Build decoupling of a scripted environment should only be considered when it provides enormous benefit, IMHO. It's never really just a "1 line command".

Comment: @NickC thanks, thats good advice :) (like your answer)

Comment: Why are subdirectories moving all the time? Are you saying your class names have no relation to their file paths and you're just moving stuff around at random? Well, there's the core of your problem. No tool can fix that automagically.

Comment: @deceze, imagine a subdirectoy like `/global_components/navbar/nav-link.php`. Now something changes, and this isn't a navbar it's just a core-nav component. We'd change the directory to be `/global_components/core-nav/nav-link.php`. I'm just using nav-link.php to be explicit, but this folder contained many classes. Now I have to go to my autoload map, and update this folder name. Yes, it's not a big deal, but it is one more thing being changed manually. Also you're comment is wrong, the tool I listed in my question does fix this automagically.

Comment: So how about naming your classes for what they do? `class Navbar\NavLink`. If its responsibilities ever change, you rename it to `class CoreNav\NavLink` and change its directory. You still have a 1:1 correlation between the class name and its file path, so it's trivially autoloadable. This naming scheme can be done in any way you choose. That's what all decent projects do these days. If there's no correlation between your classes and file paths, and you create two classes with the same name in different folders, then no tool can disambiguate that without a map.

Comment: @deceze sorry unless I'm mistaken with spl_autoload you have to specify the full path, not just the classname. If I could just say "search for any file named $classname.php in any subdirectory of /classes/, it would be fine.

Comment: And you're getting flak here because you discount autoloading without having yet shown that you fully understand a well designed autoloading system and have not presented a concrete case in which such an autoloading system is insufficient. It appears to me (and apparently most everyone else) that you do not fully understand autoloading or have not tried to properly apply it to your problem. Please update your question with a complete scenario which demonstrates that autoloading does not work for you.

Comment: See, there you go. You have not fully understood autoloading. An autoloader takes the name of a class and includes a file only based on that name. **No maps.** Take a look at the [PSR-0 spec](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-0.md) which lays out how to name your stuff so this works trivially.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37819/discussion-between-donny-p-and-deceze)

Answer (score 5):

Use [spl_autoload_register](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php) - it allows you write a short piece of code that loads a class based on its class name. If you're consistent about your naming standards your autoloader need be only a few lines of code and will load all your classes as they're required.

This is the example taken from the PHP manual:

```
// Using an anonymous function as of PHP 5.3.0
spl_autoload_register(function ($class) {
  include 'classes/' . $class . '.class.php';
});
```

Three lines of code is hardly verbose.

Comment: This assumes all of your classes are in one directory. In most projects I work on, the classes are organized into sub-directories.

Comment: This example does - and what's wrong with that? If you have split your class files into subdirectories there's nothing to stop you searching the subdirectories in the autoloader routine, or mapping class name to directory name, or any scheme you choose. From what I read in this thread you seem to have split your classes across numerous directories that don't lend themselves to anything other than a manual map, but you haven't explained your rationale for such a labour-intensive scheme.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not quite sure why you consider an auto loader to be verbose. If you adhere to a standard naming convention then an auto loader will be a handful of lines of code, which you can place in one include, and you will never write any `require` calls except that one to load your auto loader.

As for the answer to your question, no, there is nothing built in. How would it know where to get the code? PHP does not have a well-defined classpath system like Java.

You are essentially describing an auto loader anyway, albeit one that happens in code post-processing. For most smaller projects, a build step is going to add more burden than benefit to a PHP codebase.

Answer (score 0):

Got an impressive amount of flak on this question. It was interpretted as pros and cons of auto-generating an autoload. The question was meant to be "what is out there that will generate an autoload map". Here is the answer it seems:

If you want a script that will automatically inspect your PHP files, determine all the classes that are used in it, and then generate an autoload map for you, you can use this libary https://github.com/facebook/libphutil.

There do not seem to be any open-source alternatives.

The main concerns are that the work of implementing this library are greater than the work of manually writing and maintaing your autoload map used in PHP 5.3+ spl_autoload AND making sure any other libraries you use work with libphutil. From many experienced developers on this thread, it sounds like using such a library for a small project will be net negative for your time.